# Display a page in browser stored in Database using asp.net and sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, html

I am trying to display my blog content that is stored in my database in the form of raw html tags and img tags. I tried using HTML Encode before inserting data in the database and Decode while retrieving the data. After doing so I am getting an output like this.

[image]

I want to get an output like this[image]

I tried doing this but nothing worked

```
//code to put this text into the database
string text = Server.HTMLEncode(userEnteredText);

//code to put while fetching data from DB
string text = Server.HTMLDecode(userEnteredText);
```

Please note I am using Webforms and not MVC framework

I would be obliged if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: What happens when you do not use string text = Server.HTMLDecode(userEnteredText); Can you please check.

Comment: What kind of server control are you using to display the output?

Comment: @BenRobinson I am using a Label to display my output

Comment: @Amit as mentioned above I am getting the output shown in the second image

Comment: That is probably your problem then. A `Label` will automatically HTML encode what is set in the `Text` property before rendering to the browser. Use a `Literal` instead.

Comment: @BenRobinson thanks even i realized that now while searching for this problem let me try using Literalcontrol I guess this should work

Comment: @BenRobinson Could you please show me a demonstration as in how would I use the literal Control in this scenario.

Comment: If you change your <asp:Label></asp:Label> to <asp:Literal></asp:Literal> it should just  work as is.

Comment: @BenRobinson its not working even after doing that, is there anything I need to do in my server code

Comment: You do not need Server.HTMLDecode then.

Comment: @Amit I got a solution to this i used HtmlDecode twice while entering data into database and also while fetching it from database..It displays as required..thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should try [LiteralControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

With this you can inject Html into your page at runtime like so:

```
this.Controls.Add("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
this.Controls.Add(userEnteredText);
```

Further reading:

- [What is LiteralControl? Why is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274331/what-is-literalcontrol-why-is-it-used)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

//EDIT:

> Take an Water bottle

Is wrong from my little understanding of the English language. It should be "Take a water bottle" A is only attached with the suffix n in case the next word starts with a vowel (a, e, i, o, u).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response I tried using Literal control earlier but it dint seem to work.I'll try using the reference you have mentioned above and see if that does the trick